# Write RTP video stream (H264 codec) to a mp4 file

Tags: java, video-streaming, h.264, rtp, fileoutputstream

i want to store a H264 video that is recorded from a rtp (live)stream to a file.
i've tried this with a simple java program, but vlc player cannot open the file.

here is my code:

```
    try
    {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath + outputFileName);

        do
        {
            DatagramPacket in = new DatagramPacket(inData, inData.length);
            socket.receive(in);

            byte[] bytes = in.getData();

            if (curPos < buffer.length)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
                {
                    buffer[curPos] = bytes[i];
                    curPos++;

                    if (curPos >= buffer.length)
                    {
                        receivePackets = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                receivePackets = false;
            }

            Thread.sleep(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        }
        while (receivePackets);

        fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);            

        if (fos != null)
        {
            fos.close();
        }

        if (socket != null)
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the file will be created, but it's not possible to open it.
are there any header informations i've to cut of or add to the byte array to get a correct video file?

**UPDATE:**

ok, the problem seems to be the nal header information of the h264 rtp packet, because i can open a recorded h263 video with a standard rtp header (but the quality of the video is really bad).

Comment: Hi Rithe, Did you solve this problem? How to record the video from rtp packets? Did you use any RTP library to strip off the RTP headers so that you can get the NAL units to write it to a file? Regards, Ram

Comment: I haven't worked on saving the data to a file. I tried to realize a live-stream over RTP/RTSP. If you are still looking for a solution, maybe the [spydroid application](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/) includes some usefull information.

Answer (score 4):

Rtp has headers in their packets that aren't part of the h264 stream, as well as has mechanics for splitting one nal unit (essentially a single h264 "packet") over multiple packets or merging multiple nal units into one packet, both of which add metadata that can't be a part of the final product.

Additionally, the RTP stream may not contain some of the metadata necessary to play the video, especially if its negotiated over rtsp. If that's the case you'll have to pull some NAL units out of the sprop-parameter-sets in the SDP.

You can find the documentation on how all of that works here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184. It's really not as hard as it sounds.

When h264 is written to a file, each nal unit must be preceded by three 0 bytes and then a 1 byte. You can find more details on that here: https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264-201906-I/en

VLC has to be talked into playing raw h264 files. You can google that and find easy steps to do so, its not related to the code so I won't copy them here.

If you want the file as a mp4, your best using a library to do this. If you want to do it all yourself, heaven help you, but you can find the spec here: https://web.archive.org/web/20180921052457/http://l.web.umkc.edu:80/lizhu/teaching/2016sp.video-communication/ref/mp4.pdf. The https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser library is java and may do that but, has some issues. Ffmpeg is a wonderful program to do this, and I've had luck running it as a subprocess to Java and feeding its standard in and reading from its standard out.

As a side note, ffprobe is a great program, running it on a broken video file can provide some insight on what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unpack the video data from RTP packets

Comment: Consider providing more useful information in your answer, otherwise this is more of a comment.